# MVC RouteConfig custom maproute issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing, maproute

I have this in my routeConfig:

```
 routes.MapRouteLowercase(

                    name: "newProduct",

                    url: "{name}-{thisID}",


                    defaults: new

                    {

                        controller = "newProduct",

                        action = "Index",

                        name = UrlParameter.Optional


                    },
                     constraints: new { name = new MyProductConstraint() },
                    namespaces: new string[] { "khanoumiMetro.Controllers" }

                    );
```

and this is MyProductConstraint code :

```
  public class MyProductConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private KhanoumiDbContext db = new KhanoumiDbContext();


        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {

            if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
            {
                string url = values["name"].ToString();


                using (KhanoumiDbContext db = new KhanoumiDbContext())
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Open();

                    return db.tbl_Product.Any(c => c.url==url);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

it works, but if I add this :

**int id = (int)values["thisID"];**

and change this line :

return db.tbl_Product.Any(c => c.url==url);

To:

**return db.tbl_Product.Any(c => c.url==url && c.ID==id);**

I give this error when application runs : ***Specified cast is not valid.***

what happened here ?!

Comment: What is the type of the id variable ?

Comment: c.ID and id have the same type ?

Comment: @Thomas this is from my model : public int ID { get; set; }

Comment: Can you post the details of your exception and specify the line that throw the exception please

Comment: @Thomas I think the issue goes to LowercaseRoutesMVC DLL I use, because replacing routes.MapRouteLowercase to MapRoute solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed

int id = (int)values["thisID"];

to

**int id = Convert.ToInt32(values["thisID"].ToString());**

and also routes.MapRouteLowercase to MapRoute and problem solved, I thing the issue goes to LowercaseRoutesMVC DLL and I have to report this to their developer.